# Object.assign and proxies

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy-classes

Having the following object:

```
let obj = { id: 0 };
```

and the following `Proxy`:

```
let objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: (target, name) => {
    if (name == "id")
      return "id from proxy";
}});
```

Is it possible to "retain" the `Proxy` after an `Object.assign()` (or an object spread operator, which afaik is just syntax sugar for `Object.assign()`)?

```
let objProxyNew = Object.assign({}, objProxy); // i.e. {...objProxy};
```

So that `objProxyNew.id` returns `"id from proxy"`?

Comment: [Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Copying_accessors)

Comment: No. Obviously, because `{}` isn't a proxy. Please, explain your case further. Do you want to just clone a proxy?

Comment: @estus I am keeping a property read log in the proxy of an immutable object. I want to keep the logging functionality whenever somebody creates a new immutable version from the proxied object.

Comment: Who's that 'somebody'? You can probably extend Proxy and instantiate it with `new` instead of Object.assign, but this depends on the details.

Comment: @estus Specifically, I want to augment the state argument to a [Redux-style reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) (i.e. a function `st ->st`), so that I know which properties have been read inside that reducer, no matter how deeply nested and how many immutable updates were performed. EDIT: I could provide an Immutable.js-style interface, but I'd like to try natively first.

Comment: I don't think that Proxy is a proper way to do this, there are not so many good use cases for it. And it certainly can't be used in this manner, so this is likely XY problem. I would suggest to re-ask the question considering all the details you have.

Comment: I'm having @PhilipKamenarsky same issue.  In my case, I'm using an npm package in my app, and at a certain point in my code, I'm 'receiving' the proxy as a function argument.  What I need to do is to take this proxy, which is being received as the function's argument, add some properties to it and then forward it to another function.  How can I create a new instance of Proxy, that includes an exact copy of the original Proxy, and add properties to it?  I think the answer to this question automatically answers Philip's.

Answer (score 14):

Seems like I'm the third person with the exact same problem and this is the closest question on stackoverflow I've found but it has no real answers so I had to investigate it by myself.

Accidentally the behavior that Philip wants in his example is the default behavior so no change is necessary:

```js
let obj = { id: 0 };
let objProxy = new Proxy(obj, {
  get: (target, name) => {
    if (name == "id")
      return "id from proxy";
}});
    
let objProxyNew = Object.assign({}, objProxy);

console.log(objProxyNew.id); // "id from proxy"
```

But this works only for simple proxies where the names of properties on the proxied object is the same as for the final object.

### Implementing `{...obj}` for javascript proxy object

Let's take a little more complicated example, a proxy for "zip" operation (combining separate arrays of keys and values into a single object):

```
let objProxy = new Proxy({
    keys: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    values: [1, 3, 5, 7]
}, {
    get(target, name) {
        var index = target.keys.indexOf(name);
        return index >= 0 ? target.values[target.keys.indexOf(name)] : false
    }
});

console.log(objProxy.c); // 5   

console.log({...objProxy}); // {keys: undefined, values: undefined}
```

Now we got properties from the original object, but no values for them because the proxy returns nothing for "keys" and "values" properties.

As I found out, this is happening because we haven't defined trap for "ownKeys" and `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target)` is called by default.

Extending proxy with:

```
    ownKeys(target) { return target.keys; }
```

makes it even worse because no properties are cloned now at all:

```
console.log({...objProxy}); // {}
```

What is happening right now is that Object.assign calls `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` for every key returned by "ownKeys" function. By default property descriptors are retrieved from "target" but we can change it once again with another trap called "getOwnPropertyDescriptor":

```
let objProxy = new Proxy({
    keys: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
    values: [1, 3, 5, 7]
}, {
    get(target, name) {
        var index = target.keys.indexOf(name);
        return index >= 0 ? target.values[index] : false
    },
    ownKeys(target) {
        return target.keys;
    },
    getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name) {
        return { value: this.get(target, name), configurable: true, enumerable: true };
    }
});
```

`enumerable` controls which properties will be cloned and visible in console.
`configurable` must be set for proxied properties, otherwise we will get error:

> VM1028:1 Uncaught TypeError: 'getOwnPropertyDescriptor' on proxy: trap
>   reported non-configurability for property 'a' which is either
>   non-existent or configurable in the proxy target
>       at :1:1

we also need to set "writable" to "true" to be able to set property in strict mode.

`value` seems to be not used by `Object.assign` but may be used by some other framework or implementation. If it's costly to actually get a value, we can define it as a getter:

```
    get value() { return this.get(target, name); }
```

To support `in` operator and to have consistent implementation, we should also implement "has" trap. So the final implementation can look like this:

```js
let objProxy = new Proxy({
 keys: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
 values: [1, 3, 5, 7]
}, {
 get(target, name) {
  var index = target.keys.indexOf(name);
  return index >= 0 ? target.values[index] : false
 },
 ownKeys: (target) => target.keys,
 getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, name) {
  const proxy = this;
  return { get value() { return proxy.get(target, name); }, configurable: true, enumerable: true };
 },
 has: (target, name) => target.keys.indexOf(name) >= 0
});

console.log({...objProxy}); // {a: 1, b: 3, c: 5, d: 7}
```

### Implementing `[...obj]` for javascript proxy object

Another story is to support `[...objProxy]` - here, `[Symbol.iterator]` is called which we need to define in a getter:

```js
let objProxy = new Proxy({
 values: [1, 2, 3, 4],
 delta: [9, 8, 7, 6]
}, {
 get(target, name){
  if (name === Symbol.iterator) {
   return function*() {
    for (let i = 0; i < target.values.length; i ++) { yield target.values[i] + target.delta[i]; }
   }
  }
  return target.values[name] + target.delta[name];
 }
});

console.log([...objProxy]); // [10, 10, 10, 10]
```

we can also just proxy "Symbol.iterator" to original object:

```
return () => target.values[Symbol.iterator]();
```

or

```
return target.values[Symbol.iterator].bind(target.values);
```

we need to re-bind original context because otherwise iterator will be executed for Proxy object